# Incorrect syntax near 'CLUSTERED in azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database, partitioning, azure-sql-server

hi i am new to  partitioning concept

while creating table with column store index in azure SQL i am getting error like

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
>   Incorrect syntax near 'CLUSTERED'.

please find the below script that i ran in azure SQL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FactInternetSales]
(
    [ProductKey]            int          NOT NULL
  ,[OrderDateKey]          int          NOT NULL
,   [CustomerKey]           int          NOT NULL
,   [PromotionKey]          int          NOT NULL
,   [SalesOrderNumber]      nvarchar(20) NOT NULL
,   [OrderQuantity]         smallint     NOT NULL
,   [UnitPrice]             money        NOT NULL
,   [SalesAmount]           money        NOT NULL

)
WITH
(   CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
,   DISTRIBUTION = HASH([ProductKey])
,   PARTITION   (   [OrderDateKey] RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES
                    (20000101,20010101,20020101
                    ,20030101,20040101,20050101
                    )
                )
)
;
```

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/1d1d5b10-f18d-4888-9211-44f20534eae0/creating-a-table-with-column-store-index?forum=sqldatawarehousing

Comment: @SQL_M still iam getting same error

Comment: That syntax looks to be for Azure SQL Data Warehouse. See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql)  for Azure SQL Database and SQL Server.

Comment: @DanGuzman the syntax what iam using is incorrect or what i have to do for creating partitioning on my table
please guide me

Comment: @Chanukya, I added an answer.

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks for the answer  iam having doubt like partitioning can be done only one column or multiple columns ?
and more thing if i want to create clustered cloumnstore index is it possible to add columns in that (multiple columns)

Comment: SQL Server supports only a single column for partitioning, although one could use advanced specialized techniques like a computed column, I wouldn't go there. Both partitioning and columnstore are relatively advanced topics so perform due diligence. If your objective is to improve performance, much depends only your queries and workload and introducing these features can make a performance problem worse if you don't understand the implications. A clustered columnstore by definition includes all columns in the table so there is no need to specify columns at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DDL in your question is syntax for SQL Data Warehouse/SQL Parallel Data Warehouse rather than Azure SQL Database (or SQL Server on an Azure VM or on-prem). One cannot use in-line syntax for the latter plus the `DISTIBUTION` clause is not applicable in these cases.

Instead, create the partition function and scheme first and specify an `ON` clause with the partition scheme. The index may be specified using either in-line syntax like the example below or separately using `CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX...`.

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_FactInternetSales_OrderDateKey(int)
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES(
      20000101
    , 20010101
    , 20020101
    , 20030101
    , 20040101
    , 20050101
);

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PS_FactInternetSales_OrderDateKey
    AS PARTITION PF_FactInternetSales_OrderDateKey
    ALL TO ([PRIMARY]);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FactInternetSales]
(
      [ProductKey]            int          NOT NULL
    , [OrderDateKey]          int          NOT NULL
    , [CustomerKey]           int          NOT NULL
    , [PromotionKey]          int          NOT NULL
    , [SalesOrderNumber]      nvarchar(20) NOT NULL
    , [OrderQuantity]         smallint     NOT NULL
    , [UnitPrice]             money        NOT NULL
    , [SalesAmount]           money        NOT NULL
    , INDEX ccix CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE ON PS_FactInternetSales_OrderDateKey(OrderDateKey)
) ON PS_FactInternetSales_OrderDateKey(OrderDateKey);
```

Note that you need a minimum of Standard Edition and S3 Service Objective to use columnstore in Azure SQL Database. The query below will return your current configuration.

```
SELECT
      DATABASEPROPERTYEX(N'YourDatabase', 'Edition') AS Edition
    , DATABASEPROPERTYEX(N'YourDatabase', 'ServiceObjective') AS ServiceObjective;
```

If necessary, you move to a higher tier using the portal or in T-SQL with the DDL below. This may take a few minutes and you can run the above query to verify it has completed.

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase
    MODIFY (SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'S3');
```

I see you also tagged your question with SQL Server 2012. Clustered columnstore indexes were introduced in SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition and, beginning with SQL Server 2016 SP2, can be used in other SQL Server editions as well. In SQL Server 2012, only read-only non-clustered columnstore indexes are supported.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Dan Guzman  i am having a tables which is having more than 3 millions records . my intention is to create column-store index on multiple columns, which we will mainly used in where clause conditions.
already i created non clustered indexes on tables still for the better performance i want to retrieve the data fast. please suggest me which will be the better

Comment: Columnstore indexes are optimized for large scans whereas traditional indexes facilitate touching only the data needed by a particular query. Which is better depends on the mix of queries in your overall workload, including the frequency of updates. You can mix both and add partitioning on top of that. This is too broad to discuss here adequately. I suggest you peruse [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-design-guidance) and ask specific questions if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me for tier Standard S3 and later only. I was not able to set the distribution and partition.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FactInternetSales]
(
    [ProductKey]            int          NOT NULL
  ,[OrderDateKey]          int          NOT NULL
,   [CustomerKey]           int          NOT NULL
,   [PromotionKey]          int          NOT NULL
,   [SalesOrderNumber]      nvarchar(20) NOT NULL
,   [OrderQuantity]         smallint     NOT NULL
,   [UnitPrice]             money        NOT NULL
,   [SalesAmount]           money        NOT NULL

)
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE index ProductKey on FactInternetSales
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you need to select Datawarehouse instead of specific databases. If you are using Azure Data Studio there is a drop down button next to the "Change Connection". Make sure you are selecting specific datawarehouse.

Note: 
CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX is a table structure option, stores the table as a clustered columnstore index in which all of the data is compressed and stored by column. The clustered columnstore index is the default for SQL Data Warehouse and applies to all of the table data.

For more info check:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/understand-the-sql-dw-connector-with-azure-databricks/5-create-tables-perform-queries